# Spring 4 HTTP status 404

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I'm just start working with Spring 4. I want to setup Spring 4 MVC project with java configuration. I use IntelliJ Idea 13.1.6. First I create new Spring 4 MVC project from Spring MVC 3.2 template. Then I add my Java spring configuration files but when I run app its shows "Hello world" from hello template controller instead of my Home controller. Here is my project structure:

[image]

And here is my project files:

HelloController:

```
package com.spitter.mvc;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HelloController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello world!");
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

RootConfig:

```
package spittr.config;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan.Filter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.FilterType;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"spitter"},
        excludeFilters={
                @Filter(type=FilterType.ANNOTATION, value=EnableWebMvc.class)
        })
public class RootConfig {
}
```

SpittrWebAppInitializer:

```
package spittr.config;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;
public class SpittrWebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { RootConfig.class };
    }
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { WebConfig.class };
    }
}
```

HomeController:

```
package spittr.web;
import static org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.*;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/", method=GET)
    public String home() {
        return "home";
    }
}
```

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.spitter.mvc"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

web-app.xml:

```
<web-app version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Spitter.iml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsManager.isMavenModule="true" type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="FacetManager">
    <facet type="web" name="Web">
      <configuration>
        <descriptors>
          <deploymentDescriptor name="web.xml" url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml" />
        </descriptors>
        <webroots>
          <root url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/webapp" relative="/" />
        </webroots>
        <sourceRoots>
          <root url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/resources" />
          <root url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/java" />
        </sourceRoots>
      </configuration>
    </facet>
    <facet type="Spring" name="Spring">
      <configuration />
    </facet>
  </component>
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager" LANGUAGE_LEVEL="JDK_1_6" inherit-compiler-output="false">
    <output url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/target/classes" />
    <output-test url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/target/test-classes" />
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/test/resources" isTestSource="true" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/resources" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/java" isTestSource="false" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/test/java" isTestSource="true" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/target" />
    </content>
    <orderEntry type="inheritedJdk" />
    <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
    <orderEntry type="library" scope="TEST" name="Maven: org.springframework:spring-test-mvc:1.0.0.M2" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" scope="PROVIDED" name="Tomcat 8.0.151" level="application_server_libraries" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.springframework:spring-core:3.2.0.RELEASE" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.springframework:spring-web:3.2.0.RELEASE" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.springframework:spring-context:3.2.0.RELEASE" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.springframework:spring-aop:3.2.0.RELEASE" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.springframework:spring-beans:3.2.0.RELEASE" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.springframework:spring-expression:3.2.0.RELEASE" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" scope="PROVIDED" name="Maven: javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:2.1" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.springframework:spring-webmvc:3.2.0.RELEASE" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" scope="TEST" name="Maven: org.springframework:spring-test:3.2.0.RELEASE" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" scope="TEST" name="Maven: junit:junit:4.8.2" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: javax.servlet:jstl:1.2" level="project" />
  </component>
</module>
```

Why this code dont run home controller but hello controller insdead and how can I fix it?

I suspect that there is something wrong with Spitter.iml file and spring see only web.xml configuration instead of java class configuration.

Comment: You should try to narrow it down to least code that reproduces your problem sinco going through all your code is a project on its own!

Comment: Your controllers are using the same request mapping path.

Comment: No, it is not that. When I change request mapping in hello controller to @RequestMapping("/hello") I get HTTP Status 404 :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem i see is the configuration and some small details.
In your example, you are using two ways to configure the project (Java and XML).
I preffer to use Java-based configuration, it can be combined but without causing conflicts.

Your example run HelloController because it is indicated in mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml with the base-package.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.spitter.mvc"/>
```

And moreover, SpittrWebAppInitializer replace to web.xml. You must delete XML files and modify RootConfig to specify the correct package.

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"spittr"}
```

And WebConfig so be similar to this.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("spittr.web")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    // Configure a JSP view resolver
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
    }
}
```

And you can only have unique paths in your controllers, for example if you add to WebConfig the package com.spitter.mvc to @ComponentScan you will have an error.